# I am trying to get a link to go to a specific category in wordpress, any ideas?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

What I am trying to do is put 3 images up in a page on wordpress that link to and show only one category at a time. Yeah this is super hard to explain so here is the live site I am working on. http://livepoint.me (WARNING HAVE VOLUME DOWN!! A video plays once you load the page but you can click on it and pause that video.) Now then scroll down to Products. The way they are displayed is what I want to change. I want to just have 3 images representing 3 different categories and once you click that image it will show those items in that cat. So really is there a way to get a category link like that all? I hope I was clear enough if not I can make some changes to the site to represent it better.

I also forget to mention that these categories are in portfolio not posts. Pretty sure that will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting /category/category-name/ after the domain. You may have to have the permalinks set to 'Post Name' in the Settings > Permalinks option in the word press admin.

For example 
http://livepoint.me/category/news/
http://livepoint.me/category/your-product-categorey/

Comment: Yeah tried that. Didn't work out sadly. I forgot to mention that they are in my portfolios on the site. I will edit my post.